# Python using open(file) variable more than once?

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x

Is it possible to define a variable as `open("file.txt", "a")` and call it more than once so you don't have to keep typing `open("file.txt", "a")`?

I tried, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I keep getting the error message:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

My code looks like:

```
x = open("test.txt", "a")
with x as xfile:
    xfile.write("hi")

#works fine until I try again later in the script

with x as yfile:
    yfile.write("hello")
```

**Question:** Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

(My apologies if this question is a repeat, I **did** search google and SO before I posted a new question.)

Comment: why do you need to open the file more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to close the file right away, don't use a `with` statement and close it yourself when you're done.

```
outfile = open('test.txt', 'w')

outfile.write('hi\n')

x = 1
y = 2
z = x + y

outfile.write('hello\n')

outfile.close()
```

Typically you use the `with` statement when you want to open a file and do something with that file immediately, and then close it.

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as xfile:
    do something with xfile
```

However, it is best practice to take care of all your I/O with a single file at once if you can. So if you want to write several things to a file, put those things into a list, then write the contents of the list.

```
output = []

x = 1
y = 2
z = x + y
output.append(z)

a = 3
b = 4
c = a + b
output.append(c)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for item in output:
        outfile.write(str(item) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

The `with` statement closes the file automatically. It is good to do everything related to the file inside the `with` statement (opening a file multiple times is also not a good idea).

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as xfile:
    # do everything related to xfile here
```

But, if it doesn't solve your problem then don't use the `with` statement and close the file manually when the work related to that file is done.

From [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html):

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is **properly** closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

Answer (score 0):

You example doesn't make much sense without more context, but I am going to assume that you have a legitimate need to open the same file multiple times.  Answering exactly what you are asking for, you can try this:

```
x = lambda:open("test.txt", "a")

with x() as xfile:
    xfile.write("hi")

#works fine until I try again later in the script

with x() as yfile:
    yfile.write("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to use `with` statements (and indeed I think the only way they work) is `with open("text.txt") as file:`.

`with` statements are used for handling resources that need to be opened and closed.

```
with something as f:
    # do stuff with f

# now you can no longer use f
```

is equivalent to:

```
f = something
try:
    # do stuff with f
finally:    # even if an exception occurs
    # close f (call its __exit__ method)
# now you can no longer use f
```